# Master Encryption Key 1 has already been deleted

Tags: soap-api, upsert, encryption

I am trying to upsert to Salesforce using PartnerConnection SOAP API. I have no records in my custom object and get the following error when I upsert a new record:

> Master Encryption Key 1 has already been deleted

I have another cloned sandbox and is able to upsert without any errors. Maybe refresh my sandbox?Any other suggestions what the problem may be?

Comment: Any suggestions?I need to get it working else I have to open a support ticket :(

Comment: Do you have any triggers on your custom object? I don't think I've ever seen that error come back from the Partner API.

Comment: Not sure if support helped you resolve this or not, but it seems you may have encryption enabled in that sandbox, or did when you created the wsdl, and now, the encryption key has been deleted, or was never created.

Comment: There's not a chance that you're upserting with the Id of the deleted object is there?

Answer (score 1):

The error message: `Master Encryption Key 1 has already been deleted` is returned when you try to access encrypted data on the platform that can't be decrypted because the master key has been deleted.

My initial thought was that you are getting the error because you're querying or updating a record that was encrypted with a deleted key. However since you have no data for this object type in your org, that wouldn't be the case.

Another thing to do would be what [@Daniel Ballinger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/102/daniel-ballinger) mentioned. Check that no other objects are referencing your object during the upsert. This could be anything from another object being queried during a trigger, a lookup relationship, a summary field, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We recently ran into the same problem ...

**Solution:**
Salesforce support enabled a hidden setting/permission called "**Enable Encrypted Custom Objects in Full-Copy Sandboxes**" after verifying that we were the correct system administrators.

---

Note that this setting is hidden and must be enabled by Salesforce Support!
After refreshing the partial/full sandboxes again, it finally worked.
We think they disabled something in the backend during the Winter 24' release, as this is not the only issue after that release, coming up...